# how to make 3X3 grid lines in captured images from camera in android

Tags: android

how to make **3*3 grid lines** in captured images from camera in android.
Please have patience. I am new in android.

Comment: what do you mean by 3x3 grid in image? Do you mean the crop tool?

Comment: Do you want to overlay the saved images with a line grid?

Comment: yes working in overlay of saved images with line 3X3 grid